# Remove duplicates for unique constraint

Tags: liquibase

There's a cars table in my database with column `model_name`. 
I need to add the unique constraint on `model_name` column, but there are a lot of duplicate values in it.

That's why if I try `<addUniqueConstraint>`, my `changeSet` fails. So is there any way of removing all duplicates before adding unique constraint?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with liquibase [official documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/) it's not possible  out-of-the-box.

You can remove all duplicates with `<sql>` tag, and then use `<addUniqueConstraint>`.

E.G.:

```
<changeSet author="changeset-author" id="changeset-id">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="cars" columnName="model_name"/>
    </preConditions>
    <sql>
        DELETE c1 FROM cars c1, cars c2 WHERE c1.id > c2.id AND c1.model_name = c2.model_name;
    </sql>
    <!--or as was suggested by @JavaDevSweden-->
    <sql>
        DELETE FROM cars WHERE id in (SELECT c1.id FROM cars c1, cars c2 WHERE c1.id > c2.id AND c1.model_name = c2.model_name);
    </sql>
    <addUniqueConstraint tableName="cars" columnNames="model_name" constraintName="cars_model_name_unique"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: The sql in this answer only works on some databases. Tried this on an H2 in memory database on localhost and it complains about the syntax. Replaced it with 
`DELETE FROM cars WHERE id in (SELECT c1.id FROM cars c1, cars c2 WHERE c1.id > c2.id AND c1.model_name = c2.model_name); `

And this seems to work better